# How to know profile is changed to vibration mode in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I am tring one application where i take one label & one button.

I want when user clicks on that button 'Select Profile' popup screen is open.

when user selects vibration  profile  then label must be set to " Vibration On " & for other profile it is set as "Vibration Off "

I tried it but that Label is not setting immideatly after selecting profile.

This is my code

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    LabelField lbl;
    ButtonField btnOk;
    public MyScreen()
    {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen       
        setTitle("MyTitle");
        lbl=new LabelField("Set profile ");
        btnOk=new ButtonField("OK");
        btnOk.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    ApplicationManager .getApplicationManager().launch("net_rim_bb_profiles_app");
                } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(NotificationsManager.isVibrateOnly())
                {
                    lbl.setText("Vibration on");
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl.setText("Vibration Off");
                }


            }
        });
        add(lbl);
        add(btnOk);

    }
}
```

Pleease please help me ,doing it from 1 week .......

Comment: I also used by adding GlobalEvent Listener but it does not show change in device but on simulator it works.Please help if any one have idea about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override OnExposed() and wrote in that method following code

```
invalidate();
if(NotificationsManager.isVibrateOnly())
        {
            lbl.setText("Vibration on");
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.setText("Vibration Off");
        }
```

This works good for me. :) :D